# How to identify pairs of elements that can then be made into non-empty elements using xsl:iterate

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

Given this XML, I need to populate the "flag-end" elements with the right @associatedId such that I can re-create elements from the flags using xsl:iterate. I know how to create the elements, what I can't figure out is how to properly populate the @associatedId on each flag-end. (This is necessary due to third-party software we use. I'm always guaranteed an equal number of start and end flags and that the proper number of end flags will follow the proper number of start flags.)

```
    <outer>
        hello
        <flag-start associatedId="test3"/>
        <flag-start associatedId="test"/>
        <span>wor<b>---</b>ld</span>
        <flag-start associatedId="test4"/>
        <flag-end/>
        <flag-start associatedId="test2"/>
        <flag-end/>
        <flag-end/>
        <flag-end/>
        <flag-start associatedId="test5"/>
        <flag-end/>
        some more text
    </outer>
```

This is the desired XML output:

```
    <outer>
        hello
        <flag-start associatedId="test3"/>
        <flag-start associatedId="test"/>
        <span>wor<b>---</b>ld</span>
        <flag-start associatedId="test4"/>
        <flag-end associatedId="test4"/>
        <flag-start associatedId="test2"/>
        <flag-end associatedId="test2"/>
        <flag-end associatedId="test"/>
        <flag-end associatedId="test3"/>
        <flag-start associatedId="test5"/>
        <flag-end associatedId="test5"/>
        some more text
    </outer>
```

Comment: Do you have code that does part of the job? Then please show it together with the current output. Also please clarify which XSLT version you want to use as `xsl:iterate` is XSLT 3.0 so if we can use that then clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<xsl:iterate select="*">
  <xsl:param name="stack" select="()"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="self::flag-start">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <xsl:next-iteration>
        <xsl:with-param name="stack" select="@associatedID, $stack"/>
      </xsl:next-iteration>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="self::flag-end">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="associatedId" select="head($stack)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:next-iteration>
        <xsl:with-param name="stack" select="tail($stack)"/>
      </xsl:next-iteration>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:iterate>
```

Not tested. Assumes the data can be trusted to be sound.

Comment: Thank you, Dr. Kay. This is an elegant solution, and I look forward to using xsl:iterate more. May I inquire as to the use of xsl:copy-of instead of xsl:sequence? I've thought that the latter should (almost) always be preferred over the former.

Comment: I tend to use xsl:copy-of in such situations by force of habit. It won't make any difference in Saxon unless you're within a function or variable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I figured Saxon would optimize in this case.